# For `UIView.animate`, is it possible to *chain* Swift Trailing Closures?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, closures, uiviewanimation

In Swift, I would like to have several calls to `UIView.animate` run in series.  That is, when one animation finishes, then I would like another animation to continue after, and so on.

The call to `UIView.animate` has a [Trailing Closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102) which I am currently using to make a second call to `UIView.animate` to occur.

The Problem is:  *I want to do N separate animations*

From the Apple Documentation for [`UIView.animate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate)

> `completion`
>   A block object to be executed when the animation sequence ends. This block has no return value and takes a single Boolean argument that indicates whether or not the animations actually finished before the completion handler was called. If the duration of the animation is 0, this block is performed at the beginning of the next run loop cycle. This parameter may be NULL.

---

Ideally, I would like to iterate over an array of animation `duration`s and use in the calls to `animate()`

For example,

#### Goal

Iterate over an array and apply those parameters for each animation

- `let duration = [3.0, 5.0, 10.0]`
- `let alpha    = [0.1, 0.5, 0.66]`
- Xcode Version 11.4.1 (11E503a)

### What I've tried

#### Use a `map` to iterate, and  hope that it works

- Issue is that that only final animation occurs.  So there is nothing in series
- Research Q: Is it possible that I need to set a boolean in `UIView` that says animation occur in series?

```swift
let redBox = UIView()
redBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.view.addSubview(redBox)

let iterateToAnimate = duration.enumerated().map { (index, element) -> Double in
  print(index, element, duration[index])

  UIView.animate(withDuration: duration[index],  // set duration from the array
                 animations:  { () in
                   redBox.alpha = alpha[index]
                 }, completion:{(Bool)  in
                      print("red box has faded out")
  })
}
```

#### How to do one animation

```swift
let redBox = UIView()
redBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.view.addSubview(redBox)

// One iteration of Animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
               animations:  { () in
                 redBox.alpha = 0
               }, completion:{(Bool)  in
                    print("red box has faded out")
})
```

---

#### Ugly way to do chain two `animate` iterations (wish to avoid)

```swift
// two iterations of Animation, using a trailing closure
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
               animations:  { () in
                 redBox.alpha = 0
               }, completion:{(Bool)  in
                    print("red box has faded out")

}) { _ in  // after first animation finishes, call another in a trailing closure
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                 animations:  { () in
                   redBox.alpha = 0.75
                 }, completion:{(Bool)  in
                      print("red box has faded out")

  }) // 2nd animation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the parameters are few and are known at compile time, the simplest way to construct chained animations is as the frames of a keyframe animation.

If the parameters are not known at compile time (e.g. your durations are going to arrive at runtime) or there are many of them and writing out the keyframe animation is too much trouble, then just put a single animation and its completion handler into a function and recurse. Simple example (adapt to your own purposes):

```
var duration = [3.0, 5.0, 10.0]
var alpha    = [0.1, 0.5, 0.66] as [CGFloat]

func doTheAnimation() {
    if duration.count > 0 {
        let dur = duration.removeFirst()
        let alp = alpha.removeFirst()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: dur, animations: {
            self.yellowView.alpha = alp
        }, completion: {_ in self.doTheAnimation()})
    }
}
```

Comment: The recursive completion handler is a very elegant solution.  I won't ever know the parameters count at compile time.  The `.removeFirst()` was also a great tip.  It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [UIView.animateKeyframes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframeswithduration?language=objc)

```
       UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 18.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3.0/15.0, relativeDuration: 3.0/15.0, animations: {
                self.redBox.alpha = 0
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 8.0/15.00, relativeDuration: 5.0/15.0, animations: {
               self.redBox.alpha = 0.75
            })
        }) { (completed) in
           print("completed")
        }
```

Comment: This looks promising as well.

Comment: @RobLabs You may recall that that was the _first_ thing in my answer too. It's a good way, it's just a bit more work to configure.

Comment: Thanks @matt — Your answer came in first, and as I was testing your solution in my code, Arun's came in.

Comment: Oh, that's not a problem. The point is, both ways are just fine. Each has its place. You should try both!